# Jquery dynamic TextBoxes with Request.form Iteration and Save to DB

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i am Adding multiple TextBoxes with Jquery in my Application, then in code behind file i want can access the values by Request.form[name]. I want to iterate these textboxes and read values of whatever Text is entered by the user, so i can store it in database.
any idea how can i save the value of these textboxes in Database spliting each textbox values by a Comma(,)
Please guide me how to get all these textbox values in loop and then save them in DB Table

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                var counter = 2;

                $(\"#addButton\").click(function () {

                    if (counter > 10) {
                        alert(\"Only 10 textboxes allow\");
                        return false;
                    }

                    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                         .attr(\"id\", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);


                    newTextBoxDiv.html('<table><tr><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"textbox' + counter +
                          '\" id=\"textbox' + counter + '\" value=\"\" ></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"textbox' + counter +
                          '\" id=\"textbox' + counter + '\" value=\"\" ></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"textbox' + counter +
                          '\" id=\"textbox' + counter + '\" value=\"\" ></td></tr></table>');

                    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo(\"#TextBoxesGroup\");
                    return false;


                    counter++;
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have do something like this, you could easily debug by using chrome debugger tool to retrieve all values from your input boxes.

```
$('table tr td').each(function() {
     var values = "";
     values = $(this).find('input').val() + ",";
 });
```

Comment: Yes i can retrieve values by using Request.form in C# but how can i split all the values with a Comma(,) and save then into one Column on Database Table

Comment: I've edit previous code, it should work, but probably with little debugging.